# What's the song that plays in Code Geass R2 episode 25 after Todou collapses?

Tags: music, code-geass

At about 5:55 through Episode 25 of R2, Tohdoh collapses and a song begins to play. It continues to play over several of the characters' declaration of their reasons for fighting. What's the song? I've searched through the OST as well as unreleased tracks but haven't been able to find it.

The episode can be watched here:
https://www.funimation.com/shows/code-geass/final-turn-re/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called ***Fascination***, the 40th track on disc 2 of a limited edition of *[CODE GEASS Lelouch of the Re;surrection O.S.T.](https://vgmdb.net/album/82214)*.

Comment: I added more context based on the only hint from the song title, so I hope this is the correct one. Otherwise, please [edit] and fix the info. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've ended a 5-year search. Cheers!